# Installing arch linux - unable to format filesystem

Tags: linux, unix, multi-boot, arch-linux

I had Centos & Windows systems dual booted previously. I am replacing Centos with Arch now.

I have Centos's /boot installed on /dev/sda8 and / on /dev/sda9

When I try the following  command on Arch(booted using USB) to format /dev/sda9, it doesn't allow me to do.

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda9
/dev/sda9 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

I checked whether the device is currently mounted. It is NOT! 
Googling the error brings up certain sites which are related to disk being setup as RAIDs. I am not using RAID too and the arch is currently being mounted on /dev/sdb(USB device).

I was able to format /dev/sda8(which was /boot partition) using

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda8
```

which means I have borked the ability to boot to Windows.
Please help.

Edit:
Reproducing(partial) output of `lsblk -f` command by typing,

```
NAME                          FSTYPE        LABEL
sda
|--sda1                       vfat          DellUtility
|--sda2                       ntfs
|--sda3                       ntfs
|--sda4
|--sda5                       ntfs
|--sda6                       ntfs
|--sda7                       ntfs
|--sda8                       ext4
|--sda9                       LVM2_member
   |--VolGroup00-LogVol00     ext3
   |--VolGroup00-LogVol01     swap
sdb                           iso9660        ARCH_201310
|--sdb1                       iso9660        ARCH_201310
|--sdb2                       vfat           ARCHISO_EFI
```

Comment: Looks like /dev/sda9 was an LVM(not sure what that is, need to read more!). After I did an

    dmsetup remove VolGroup00=LogVol00
    dmsetup remove VolGroup00-LogVol01

I was able to format!

Comment: Well done on answering your own question, tempted to write it up as an official answer?  I'll upvote you if you do :) - LVM stands for Logical Volume Manager and to cut a long story short, is a great way to add storage to system without having to create new mounts or even system downtime in some instances.  Good WP article here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)

Comment: @sgtbeano I wish I could, but new users can not answer their own questions apparently in less than 8 hours. Thanks for the info.

Comment: :( - I've up voted both your comments

Comment: This is a good question and answer. After your 8 hours have passed, you should post your answer. One suggestion for the question though. Tell us *how* you verified `/dev/sda9` was not mounted. did you do `mount | grep sda9` and receive no output? Some other means?

Answer (score 1):

This answer was originally posted as a comment by the OP, who did not return to answer the question. Because Stack Overflow permits posting somebody's comment as an answer if it is deemed to be such, I am answering 'on behalf of' the OP, incorporating @sgtbeano's comment about LVM.

It looks like `/dev/sda9` was a [Logical Volume Manager (LVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)). After I did the following, I was able to format! :

```
dmsetup remove VolGroup00=LogVol00 ; dmsetup remove VolGroup00-LogVol01
```